# How can I customize twitter bootstrap to target my website to Smart phone and Tab only?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am building a website which I need to target only for phone and tablets only. On a larger screen layout such as desktop and laptops the site layout should be same as mobile or tablet.

I tried Mobile-First Bootstrap Grid customize css but no luck. https://github.com/G5/mobile-first-bootstrap-grid

Answer (score 0):

you can customize bootstrap grid system variable here:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html#variables

Comment: In the Customize page I don't see any parameter wherein I can specify any specific screen size.

Comment: Please see "Grid system" part. You can specify there number of column and column width as per your screen size.

Comment: For mobile and tab what should be the ideal value for number of column and column width?

Comment: For tab, total width should be 768.

Comment: For Mobile, total width should be 320.